# Inserting data into an array

Tags: php, sql

I am quite new to PHP but i'm  a quite experianced Java programmer.

I know what i want to achieve with my code i.e

`while(result.Hasnext()){ array.add(result.next)}`

Now i have the following php code:

```
$myArr = array();
$query = 'SELECT message from shoutbox';
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

how would i add all of the data i get into an array in php? I know this is rather simple but i have been looking everywhere for examples and simply havnt found one.

**My full db class**

```
<?php
class database{
    private $server = "db9.meebox.net";
    private $usedb = "marcrasm_website";
    private $user = "******";
    private $pass = "******";
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->usedb);
        if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
            printf('Error: Connect failed: %s', $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function sendMessage($message){
        $currentTime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
        $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $query = "INSERT INTO shoutbox VALUES ('NULL','$message','$date')";
        $this->db->query($query);
    }
    public function loadMesssages(){
        $query = 'SELECT message from shoutbox ORDER BY created DESC';
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
            //no results
        }else{
            // returned at least one result.
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $myArr [] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $myArr;
    }
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using `PDO`. The simplest solution would be:

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
$array = $result->fetchAll();
```

Btw, how could you fail to achieve that using the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Update:

After you've edited the question I see that you are not using `PDO`. However, it would be too much to edit on your code to help you with just a single answer (without giving you the whole solution). You'll make it! ;)

Comment: PHP Data Object. If you do not know this tell us how you are accessing the db.

Comment: i have posted my full db code (without passwords ofcourse) can you please look at it and see what im doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you are doing it wrong too much to explain. (once you know this you'll confirm). check the link that I gave you and start step by step

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){   
    //no results
}else{
    // returned at least one result.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $myArr [] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

new mysqli(..) then mysql_... you have used wrong library. If you use mysqli use it to fetch data

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $myArr[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you query'ing the db?

But basicly you cann add to an array in PHP like this:
`$some_array[] = "some value";`

or to set a specific key:

`$some_array[3] = "another_value";`

If your query returns an array you can simply assign the return to your array (your `$return` is an array right now)

However this depends strongly on the return type of your `db->query()`

To sum this up:

You can add a single item to an array or just assign the variable to an other array. There are also some functions like `array_merge` which combines to array. Just have a look at some array related PHP-manual pages.

Answer (score -1):

It can be as simple as this:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $myArr[] = $row;
}
```

If no rows are selected by the query, the loop condition will be false on the first run so the array will remain empty.

Comment: When i try this i get the following <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in <b>/home/marcrasm

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you are using what looks like PDO, so this won't apply. If you use the mysql or mysqli API to connect to your database and run queries, this code will do what you need.

Comment: For PDO, hek2mgl's answer will do the job...